# declaring a startdate & endate using joda time?

Tags: java, jodatime

I've already imported the joda libary and I was able to import the Easy Reader class. However, I need help formatting correctly so I can calculate the days in between, and yes, I am aquainted with the MM/dd/yyyy, but I've used integers. Do I need to import anything else? I'm really new at joda, so please be patient, thanks. Everything seems to work fine, but I cant find the right syntax that will help me find the difference between the two dates, and I can't find it.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
class starter{
public static void BdayPrgm(String args[]){

System.out.println("Please Enter Today's Month: ");
        EasyReader month = new EasyReader();
        //this will indentify it as an INT, not a string.
        //quest is a question btw.
        todaysmon = month.readInt();

        System.out.println("What number is today?: ");
        EasyReader currentday = new EasyReader();
        todayday = currentday.readInt();



        System.out.println("What is today's year?: ");
        EasyReader todayyear = new EasyReader();
        year = todayyear.readInt();

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("What is your BdayMonth?: ");
        EasyReader thatyear = new EasyReader();
        bdaymon = thatyear.readInt();

        System.out.println("What is your Bday #?: ");
        EasyReader thatday = new EasyReader();
        thatgr8day = thatday.readInt();

        System.out.println("What is the bdayyear?: ");
        EasyReader bdayyear = new EasyReader();
        bdayyr = bdayyear.readInt();


        int age;
        age = year - bdayyr;


        //we can get start date by putting test maybe?
        DateTimeZone LA = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");
        LocalDate start = new LocalDate(year,todaysmon,todayday);
        LocalDate end = new LocalDate(year,bdaymon,thatgr8day);

        int Days;
        //code isn't compileing below. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
        Days.daysBetween(new LocalDate(start),new LocalDate(end)).getDays();

        //int days = d.getdays;

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println(CELEB1+" is going to be "+age+" years old in X days!");
```

}

```
}
```

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
int Days;
Days.daysBetween(new LocalDate(start),new LocalDate(end)).getDays();
```

should be something like

```
int dayCount = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();
```

Because `start` and `end` are already `LocalDate`(s) and you want to save the result of the call. Also, you should only need **one** `EasyReader` *instance*. And, you'll need to add

```
import org.joda.time.Days;
```

Comment: C:\Users\owner\Desktop\BdayAssignment>javac *.java
starter.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
                        int dayCount = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable Days
  location: class starter
1 error

C:\Users\owner\Desktop\BdayAssignment>pause
Press any key to continue . . . It still isn't hasn't compiled. I'm trying to find the right parameters, but it's wrong...

Comment: @PYRO912 `import org.joda.time.Days;`

Comment: It works. Thanks. forgot to add the import